# Is there a canonical for JavaScript module questions?

Tags: discussion, canonical

**TL;DR**: thanks to a lot of historical baggage navigating and integrating the (at least) four different module systems in JavaScript is unreasonably confusing and so we get questions about it all the time. Is there a good canonical that explains the differences and the why?

CJS. [ESM](https://hacks.mozilla.org/2018/03/es-modules-a-cartoon-deep-dive/). AMD. [UMD](http://jargon.js.org/_glossary/UMD.md). `"<script type="module"></script>"`. `"type": "module"` in `package.json`. Various loaders and bundlers. TypeScript.

There are many many subtle nuances and incompatibilities in the various flavors of JavaScript modules:

- [CommonJS](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CommonJS) (CJS) modules use `require` and `module.exports` which are

  - Synchronous (blocking)
  - Dynamic, i.e. module resolution occurs while the code is running
  - Don't deal well with circular references.
  - The module exports can be a single value *or* a map of names-to-values.
  - Not supported natively in the browser, but are natively supported in Node.js.
- ESM modules use `import` and `export` which are

  - Asynchronous (although that's hidden from the programmer)
  - Static i.e. module resolution occurs *before* the code runs.
  - Deals (with caveats) with circular references.
  - Has no concept of a single value export, instead has a special
    `default` export.
  - Are technically supported (although rarely used directly) in the
    browser
  - technically natively supported in Node.js with the `.mjs` file
    extension although there are *significant* caveats around
    interoperability with `require` and the presence/absence of
    certain things like `__dirname` and `import.meta`, and the
    necessity of setting the type to module in the *[package.json](https://docs.npmjs.com/cli/v9/configuring-npm/package-json/)* file.
  - Require the `.js` file extension for imports that aren't
    node_modules imports in node, and is required for every import in
    the browser: omitting it is a [Webpack](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Webpack)/TypeScript thing.
- TypeScript modules

  - Are basically ESM without the file extension requirement...
  - ...**EXCEPT** that they may be compiled to *either* CJS or ESM,
    and you can alternatively use `require` with the `@types/node`
    package, just in case you weren't confused enough already.
- AMD modules

  - Asynchronous
  - Dynamic
  - Not natively supported anywhere.
  - Kind of a historical oddity at this point but still in use some
    places.

That was painful to write.

And that's just an incomplete summary of some of the gotchas and differences, much less an explanation of the history of *why* JS modules came to be such a cluster****. There are probably some important errors/omissions in all of that (e.g., I didn't talk about dynamic `import` or how tools like Webpack/Rollup/[Parcel](https://hungryturtlecode.com/tutorials/parcel-bundler/)/whatever change the sitch): it should really be a community wiki answer or something like that were it can be refined by multiple experts over time. Do we already have a good canonical for this? I feel like I use 20% of this (a different 20% each time) on JS module-related questions all the time.

Comment: I mean... no, because for each of those there's dozens, if not hundreds, of different "problems" that may need to be "solved".

Comment: @KevinB I mean, I don't disagree, but 90% of those problems boil down to "why does my CJS/ESM idiom not work in a ESM/CJS context?".

Comment: (I'm expressly *not* saying there *shouldn't* be, ;)

Comment: What is *"the sitch"*?

Comment: @PeterMortensen I assume OP is referring to how tools like Webpack introduced a paradigm shift in how external resources or modules are added to a project.

Comment: @PeterMortensen slang term for "situation". Webpack allows (requires?) you to skip the file extension in an import statement, which is against the standard but has become a defacto standard of it's own (it's probably more widely used than the actual standard, to the point where many devs aren't actually aware that the standard requires it). Basically what TylerH was saying.

Comment: Start by identifying questions that you'd like to see answered, and that fit the format - i.e., are clear and properly focused. Then look for the corresponding canonicals. You cannot expect "a" canonical, singular, for JS module "questions", plural, unless they are really all the same question (in the way that "how do I frob a Widget" is the same question as "how do I frob a Sprocket" only when it works the same way for both, there's a good reason to expect it to work the same way for both, and people who ask these questions are just specifying needlessly).

Comment: No, there is not a single canonical question to explain everything - that would require a blog article (series) or book, not a SO answer. I doubt you could ask an on-topic catch-all question. There are, however, [a lot of frequent questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/es6-modules?tab=Frequent).